# How to marshal pointer types when calling C dll function in C#

Tags: marshalling

I need to call a c function imported from a dll.  I can find how to import the api function but I am unsure how to marshal all the types the function expects as paramters.  Particularly pointer types.

Example function signature might be...

Result_Type get_signal_value( SIG* sig, char* name, int *value );

where SIG is a sturcture containing various items.  eg.
struct SIG
{
char sig_id[16];
int sig_ptr;
HW_ADDR_TYPE hw_info;
};

and

struct HW_ADDRESS_TYPE
{
   short channel_no;
   unsigned char chassis;
   unsigned char slot;
   unsigned char link;
   unsigned char filler;
};

I can find that to Marshal this type I need to describe the structure layout...

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   public class HW_ADDRESS_TYPE
   {
      short channel_no;
      byte chassis;
      byte slot;
      byte link;
      byte filler;
   } ;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   public class SIG
   {
      public const int LEN_SID = 16;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = LEN_SID)]
      public string sig_id;
      int sig_ptr;
      HW_ADDRESS_TYPE hw_info;
   };

but seem to have problems here.  have I done this correctly?

Same for the int* in the example.

Any help would be great.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SIG
{
    // describe the fields here
}

[DllImport("lib.dll")]
static extern bool get_signal_value(SIG sig, string name, float value);
```

Which you might call:

```
SIG sig = new SIG();
sig.Field1 = value1;
sig.Field2 = value2;
bool result = get_signal_value(sig, "abc", 1.5f);
```

Comment: can you be more specific re. the layout of the structure?  Are you saying that to marshal a pointer value you have to do nothing?  See edited question...

Comment: Try using `struct` instead of `class` for `SIG` and `HW_ADDRESS_TYPE` types in C#